# Remmina sessions on different screens

Tags: rdp

Can Remmina run concurrent sessions (to separate remote hosts) on different monitors?

eg:

- Session 1 (connected to a Windows box) on my left monitor
- Session 2 (connected to a Linux box) on my right monitor?

Answer (score 2):

There's an answer in [the Remmina GitLab issues](https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/issues/1795#note_130506555)

Preferences -> Appearance -> Tab interface -> None

There are other options for grouping, but "None" will use no tabs at all and everything will be a new window. You'll probably also want to untick "Always show tabs" as well.